# How to pass multiple value in like clause of Criteria api?

Tags: java, criteria, criteria-api

Here is what i am implementing.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = query.from(User.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    Expression<String> userExpression = statusRoot.get("firstName");

     for (String str : firstNames) {
        predicates.add(cb.like(userExpression, "%" + str + "%"));
    }
```

I want to apply like clause on list of values but its appending all Predicate with AND operator. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually code given in example does not show use of predicates. That is where the problem is. I will assume it is equivalent to rather typical:

```
//conjunction, will combine with 'AND'
query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#where(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...)), it will combine Predicates with `AND`:

> Modify the query to restrict the query result according to the
>   conjunction of the specified restriction predicates

One way to combine Predicates with `OR` is simply using CriteriaBuilder.[or](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#or(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...)):

```
//disjunction, will combine with 'OR'
Predicate firstNameLikeAnyOf = cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
query.where(firstNameLikeAnyOf);
```